# Stop Cloudflare from caching redirects

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I have a bit of a unique situation here.

We have a domain that hosts user uploaded media (that has had image operations applied to it) (usermedia.com). Media is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket and Cloudflare sits in front of this bucket.

If a user requests an image, they might browse to https://usermedia.com/my-image-resize-200-200.jpg.

If this image exists, it is served, otherwise Amazon S3 does a 302 redirect (via Routing Rules) to https://app.com/generate/my-image-resize-200-200.jpg which generates the resized image, uploads it to S3, and then does another redirect back to https://usermedia.com/my-image-resize-200-200.jpg. This time the file exists in S3 and is served.

The problem is when we have the Cloudflare proxy enabled - it caches redirects and so if the media doesn't exist, Cloudflare gets stuck in a continuous redirect cycle. I've tried using a 307 redirect but the problem persists.

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's CloudFlare and not your browser or Amazon that is the issue? I've built an exact function into a site but on it's server instead of AS3. CloudFlare handles it just fine. The next call to the image loads it nearly instantly.

Comment: I have a similar "redirect if not found" setup with CloudFront rather than Cloudflare, but I use CloudFront > HAProxy (EC2) > S3.  HAProxy changes the 403 to 302, sets `Location:`, and sets `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` to address this issue... the location is actually unchanged, except a query string is added to indicate resize action and HAProxy sends these to the resizer server.  Then the resizer actually saves to S3 but doesn't redirect -- it just returns the image, to avoid potential S3 eventual consistency issues. But I'll go back through my notes on redirect rules.

Comment: @Jules makes a good point.  S3 is eventually consistent on new object creation under one condition: if you already did a `GET` before the object was created -- and you did, by design.

Comment: @Jules I'm fairly sure it's Cloudflare because when I turn off the Cloudflare proxy it works normally (except Cloudflare doesn't cache images etc, so pointless).

Comment: You should set up a page rule in cf to never cache nor optimize those images - hopefully in a directory you can wildcard. See if the problem persists.

Comment: @Jules how do you propose I do that? If the browser requests https://usermedia.com/my-image.jpg then doesn't the path have to be the same before and after the redirect?

Comment: Disable caching on the initial URL. You can set up a rule like `usermedia.com/*.jpg`. In that rule disable caching. Would have been nicer if those images were in a directory, but temporarily for testing this is fine.

Comment: @Jules Oh, I understand now. That's what I've already done to get it working, as soon as I disable that rule the redirect loops happen again.

Comment: Are you using some other page rule that is interfering? You may want to go with @Michael-sqlbot's suggestion - instead of redirecting, serve the binary data 'manually'. With that it won't matter if the url is cached or not.

Comment: Were you able to get this straightened out?

Comment: @Jules not yet, I've just disabled caching for now but it's not ideal

Answer (score 1):

I have an exact same setup and some problem. I found out that the problem is indeed the clouldflare. When the image doesn't exist, S3 returns a 307 pointing to the resizer endpoint, the problem here is that cloudflare adds the cache header (e.g.: cache-control:public, max-age=691200) because probably you have on the caching tab the option Browser Cache Expiration set, so when the browser gets the response it will cache it (because a cache-control header is present), so the next request will be served from browser cache.

UPDATE:

A quick solution may be simple. On cloudflare set Browser Cache Expiration to "Respect Existing Headers", this way cloudflare will not add the headers that make browser cache the response. If you still want images to be cached locally, simply set the cache-control header directly on the S3 image when creating it from the resize script

```
S3.putObject({
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    CacheControl: 'max-age=604800',
    Key: finalKey,
})
```

If you have other assets (e.g. css or javascript, etc) you can set the CacheControl header for them as well from the aws console, or, if you have them in some folder, let's say "foo", you can go to Cloudflare, create a page rule and instruct to set the Browser Cache TTL for all files under the "foo" folder.

I know this is a late answer but hope to help people having the same problem in the future

Answer (score -1):

At the moment I see that Cloudflare doesn't cache 307 redirects. First query:

[image: first]

Second query:

[image]

You can set the respose code in S3 redirection rules like this:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
    <HostName>app.com</HostName>
    <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
  </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```